# React App in a Child Route of an existing Web site

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to build a Sub route of a main website in React. My doubt is how to structure the Routes in React router.

> Eg. Main Website starts at '/' and when '/react' appears the react 
>   app should take over.

How should the Routes be structure like

```
<Route path="/">
  <Route path="/react">
    //...rest of the child routes
  </Route>
</Route>
```

> OR

There should be a server side express route with "/react" which starts the react app
Something like this

```
app.get('/react',(req,res)=>{
  match({history,routes,location},(error,redirect,renderProps)=>{
       //..rest of the code
  })
})
```

In that case can the routes be structured this way?

```
<Route path='/'>
 <IndexRoute/>
//..rest of the routes
</Route>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With React Router component you specify routes only in client side. So on server side it should be like this:

```
app.get('*',(req,res)=>{
   // return Index page for every GET request
})
```

On the client side there is no one right way to implement this. The simplest way is to use nested routes like this:

```
<Route path="/">
  <Route path="/react">
    //...rest of the child routes
  </Route>
</Route>
```

Another way to create variable with `/react` routes and insert it in core routes (you can import this variable from another file in the future and realize module structure for your router):

```
const reactSubRoute = 
        <Route path="/react">
           //...rest of the child routes
        </Route>

<Route path="/">
   {reactSubRoute}
</Route>
```

Using `<IndexRoute />` may be not necessary for your situation. If you want more info about `<IndexRoute />` [read this article.](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/IndexRoutes.md)